# Java: add elements from a list to another with conversion

Tags: java, collections

I am sure there are some functions to shorten my code below with some "lamda, map, Collections"-magic that does not need the loop to read from lsta and insert into lstb.

```
List <Integer> lsta = new ArrayList <Integer> ();
// ... insert into lsta

List <String> lstb = new ArrayList <String> ();
for (Integer a : lsta)
{
   lstb.add (foo (a));
}
```

Comment: I can't help but notice that you didn't ask a question.

Comment: `List<String> lstb = lsta.stream().map(a -> foo(a)).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Java 8+ (result list is mutable, i.e can be changed, sorted, ..)

```
List<String> lstb = lsta.stream().map(a -> foo(a)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

For Java 16+ (result list is immutable, i.e cannot be added to or sorted ..)

```
List<String> lstb = lsta.stream().map(a -> foo(a)).toList();
```